# canvas2Draw - how to connect view class to the canvas2

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02HzO.png) I'm new in ***android*** studio and I'm having problem with drawing.
Upon execution it does not work

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View eissa=new eissa(this);
    setContentView(eissa);
}
```

}

```
class eissa extends View {
private Canvas canvas2;
private Bitmap backingbitmap;
public eissa(Context context) {
        super(context);
  backingbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas2= new Canvas(backingbitmap);
}



   @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(0,50,100,null);
    canvas2.drawCircle(0,50,100,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backingbitmap,0,0,null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 2.

There is a problem with the canvas.drawCircle() because there is no Paint argument (last one). The drawCircle doc says : "Paint: The paint used to draw the circle This value cannot be null."

So you can create a Paint in the constructor to pass to the drawCircle methods:

```
class eissa extends View {
    private Canvas canvas2;
    private Bitmap backingbitmap;
    Paint viewPaint;

    public eissa(Context context) {
        super(context);
        backingbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas2= new Canvas(backingbitmap);
        viewPaint = new Paint();
        viewPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000); // set your desired color here context.getColor(R.color....);
        viewPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 50, 100, viewPaint);
        canvas2.drawCircle(0, 50, 100, viewPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(backingbitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

---

### 1.

The view's dimensions are not specified anywhere causing the platform to use the default LayoutParams which have the layout_width and layout_height  equal to WRAP_CONTENT so the view is not visible. To address ui issues you can use Tools / Layout inspector which can help identify the cause (incorrect dimensions).
Here is a good tutorial about [measuring custom views](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d).

The quickest fix would be to specify dimensions using LayoutParams in setContentView:

```
// replace setContentView() in onCreate() with this
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
setContentView(eissa, lp);
```